# Laravel got route list issue

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-10

I am getting this error:

```
Error: Ziggy error: route 'contract/generatePDF?id=517&pickupKM=0' is not in the route list.
```

but is defined in the web.php:  `GET|HEAD        contract/generatePDF`

```
Route::get('contract/generatePDF', [App\Http\Controllers\ContractController::class, 'generatePDF'])->name('contract.generatePDF');
```

and from the vue I am calling this function:

```
router.visit(route("contract/generatePDF?id="+props.contract.id+"&pickupKM="+pickupKM));
```

also tried like this:

```
router.visit("/contract/generatePDF?id="+props.contract.id+"&pickupKM="+pickupKM);
```

Comment: It looks like the [`route`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/helpers#method-route) helper is expecting a route name, not an url. However, I'm not sure if, in your example, it's the same route function as the one in laravel.

Comment: @Nicolas I have it. I defined it like this: ```name('contract.generatePDF');``` also I tried without

Answer (score 3):

Ziggy expects a route name that matches one of your Laravel-side routes. Query parameters are passed separately; they are not part of the route's name.

https://github.com/tighten/ziggy#query-parameters

```
route('contract.generatePDF', {
    id: props.contract.id,
    pickupKM: pickupKM
});
```

Your issue is two-fold; you're giving Ziggy the route's URL (`contract/generatePDF`) instead of its name (`contract.generatePDF`), and you're including the query string in the name, which Ziggy doesn't automatically parse out for you.

Comment: I changed like this: ```router.visit(route('contract.generatePDF', { id: props.contract.id, pickupKM: pickupKM}));``` but now I am getting 404, not found

Comment: @Vannian Time to debug. What URL do you wind up on? What URL did you *expect* to wind up on? What's different? Do your variable values match what you expect? Is your 404 a "model not found" issue? Since it's presumably a PDF download, have you tried `window.location.href` to go there instead of using the Vue router?

Comment: The url is this: ```http://127.0.0.1:8000/contract/generatePDF?id=525&pickupKM=0``` I am not returning any pdf, now I just want that the endpoint reaches the method.

Comment: Really no answer for this, strange

Comment: Likely a laravel 404 because your id does not match, try to see if you have a model not found exception

Comment: my function is defined like this:  ```public function generatePDF(Request $request)``` and I tried to call like this: ```http://127.0.0.1:8000/contract/generatePDF?someval=232&pickupKM=12```

Comment: I found the issue. Somehow the word ```contract``` is the cause of it. I have already defined ```Route::resource('contract', ContractController:class)```. And then I defined this ```Route::get('contract/generatePDF', ContractController::class)``` and getting 404. I just changed the order and is working.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. Somehow the word `contract` is the cause of it.
I have already defined

```
Route::resource('contract', ContractController:class)
```

And then I defined this

```
Route::get('contract/generatePDF', ContractController::class)
```

and getting 404.

I just changed the order and is working:

```
Route::get('contract/generatePDF', [ContractController::class, 'generatePDF'])->name('contract.generatePDF');
Route::resource('contract', App\Http\Controllers\ContractController::class);
```

Comment: `Route::resource('contract')` creates routes like `Route::get('contract/{contract}')`, so that makes sense.